# For vacation vs on vacation

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> I want to go to Spain **on** a vacation with you.
>   vs
>   I want to go to Spain **for** a vacation with you.

What's the difference?

I know, FOR indicates purpose of going to Spain. 
But here, is the use of ON appropriate?

What does, to Spain ON VACATION indicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two sentences mean the same thing. 'On a vacation' is used more commonly than 'for a vacation'.

One very minor difference between the two phrases, which does not apply in this case is :

> 1/ If I said, "I am going to Spain on my vacation", there is a possibility that I may also go somewhere else as well.
>
> 2/ If I said, "I am going to Spain for my vacation", then it is unlikely that I will go anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

If I was telling someone why I wanted to go to Spain, the preposition I'd likely use most often is ***to***:

> I want to go to Spain **to** see the Prado museum.
>
> I want to go to Spain **to** visit the beaches.
>
> I want to go to Spain **to** take a vacation.

However, the expression *on (a) vacation* is idiomatic, so we may not need that ***to***:

> I want to go to Spain **on** a vacation.
>
> I want to go **on** vacation to Spain.

Yet *vacation* can also be used as a verb:

> I want to vacation in Spain with you.

(which is the way I'd probably write your sentence.)

Getting back to your question, though, either one is grammatical, and I think they essentially mean the same thing:

> I want to go to Spain **on** a vacation with you.
>
> I want to go to Spain **for** a vacation with you.

**Bottom line**: Prepositions are very flexible. It's not always a matter of one is correct and the alternative is wrong. Sometimes we can swap a preposition and the meaning won't change:

> I have to go to Spain **on** business.
>
> I have to go to Spain **for** business.

But other times they can't be swapped:

> I want to go to Spain **for** two weeks. (**not** "on two weeks")
>
> I have to go to Spain **on** Monday. (**not** "for Monday")

And other times, either one can work, but the meaning might shift some:

> I will go to Spain **for** my birthday. (*I will celebrate my birthday by going to Spain*)
>
> I will go to Spain **on** my birthday. (*the trip to Spain coincides with my birthday; my birthday may or may not be the primary reason for my visit*)